# Ruby regex: validate unix file path

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to validate unix file path using regex.

I have [`\A[0-9a-zA-Z\_\-\/]+\z`](http://rubular.com/r/4BV804NJpv)

But this still allows double slashes like `this//is//allowed`

How do I make sure double slashes are not allowed?

edit 1

I want to allow _, -, alphanumeric values as long as they form valid unix directory path. Just want to make sure that `//` is forbidden. THanks

Comment: give some examples and expected output..please

Comment: No part of your regex attempts to prevent duplicate forward slashes from being matched.

Comment: What about escaped characters, like `/this\ is\ valid`? You sure you want to do this "by hand", and with a regex? When regex is your hammer, everything looks like a thumb.

Comment: But `//` is valid in a Unix path.

Comment: @DaveNewton O didn't know that. Thanks for the info. For this problem I have though, I should prohibit it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should move the slash outside the character class, and make it optional. And then add quantifier on the character class and the slash combined, to repeat their combination for 1 or more times:

```
\A(?:[0-9a-zA-Z_-]+\/?)+\z
```

See on http://rubular.com/r/77kvWAoI4e

```
(?:
  [0-9a-zA-Z_-]+   # Original character class without `/`. 
  \/?                # An optional slash (Because the string need not end with `/`
)+                   # 1 or more repetition of their combination
```

And you don't need to escape `_` in regex. And also `-` when used at the end of character class.

And finally, your character class can be reduced to - `[\w-]`. So, your regex can be reduced to:

```
\A(?:[\w-]+\/?)+\z
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the target character along with the number of times it is repeated

`/\/{2}/`

Comment: I think you misunderstood the requirement.